# How to use OpenSSL exacly?

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, openssl, md5

Okay, I need to use md5() function from OpenSSL library, but when I compile gcc gives me an error - "undefined reference to md5". I tried few things, which I found in different StackOverFlow questions, but still no effect.

First of all I installed packages (Ubuntu 13.04):

> sudo apt-get install openssl
>
> sudo apt-get install libssl-dev

In my source I included  openssl/md5 and I tried to compile  everything this way:

> gcc main.c -lssl -lcrypto

or

> gcc main.c -L/home/usr/lib -lssl -lcrypto

What am I missing? Please help.

Comment: You need to show us your code, and the actual commands you are running, and the actual output of those commands, including any error messages.

Comment: After installing `libssl-dev` and compiling with `gcc main.c -lssl -lcrypto`, things should have worked. That's because `apt-get` puts the libraries in `/usr/lib` and the compiler/linker could find them. So you have another problem that's not readily apparent. Clean your project and start again or show us the make command.

Comment: Also, you sometimes need to link against `-ldl` and `-lpthread`, too. Add them after `-lssl` `-lcrypto`.

Comment: The line i include is `#include <openssl/md5.h>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that your OpenSSL is compiled with `no-md5` option. So, download OpenSSL and build it with md5 if required.